# Unity Universal Windows App Development

Tags: visual-studio-2017, unity-game-engine, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I am trying to create windows store build using Visual studio 17 with Universal Windows App Development tool.

When I create a build from unity, it creates a visual studio solution but finishes with a lot of errors.

When I try to build the resulting visual studio solution, it fails to generate a build.

I am attaching related settings and build outputs screenshot in sequence that I encounter them.

My unity build settings
[image]

Unity console errors on Build complete

[image]

Vs error on opening/building VS solution output

[image]

Can anybody help with this UWA tool. I am trying this for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Unity .Net version and UWP .NET are not the same. They have much in common and also some differences.

For instance, you can build and import in VS. Then you have async/await available which are not in Unity.

For your case, here's an excerpt from there : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185488.aspx

> "This topic displays the types in the System.Security and
>   System.Security.Principal namespaces that are included in .NET for UWP
>   apps.  Note that .NET for UWP apps does not include all the members of
>   each type. For information about individual types, see the linked
>   topics. The documentation for a type indicates which members are
>   included in .NET for UWP apps."